# hi im actually trying to deploy my app on heroku , it says build succeeded but if run that link its says application error. i use node.js

Tags: heroku

heroku logs -t
2020-11-28T11:17:07.450971+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user arasusivakumar3@gmail.com
2020-11-28T11:17:07.450971+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user arasusivakumar3@gmail.com
2020-11-28T11:17:07.584346+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user arasusivakumar3@gmail.com
2020-11-28T11:17:07.584346+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user arasusivakumar3@gmail.com
2020-11-28T11:18:07.337688+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user arasusivakumar3@gmail.com
2020-11-28T11:18:07.337688+00:00 app[api]: Deploy de83953d by user arasusivakumar3@gmail.com
2020-11-28T11:18:07.355333+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user arasusivakumar3@gmail.com
2020-11-28T11:18:08.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-11-28T11:18:11.464653+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-11-28T11:18:11.509940+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-11-28T11:18:11.513306+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-11-28T11:18:13.233346+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `: node app.js`
2020-11-28T11:18:15.193838+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-11-28T11:18:15.239646+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-11-28T11:18:21.795309+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=secure-plains-88138.herokuapp.com request_id=0ed67f95-3399-4a2d-b2d7-b52b723c8dd5 fwd="92.97.70.247" dyno= connect= service2020-11-28T11:18:23.118416+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico"
host=secure-plains-88138.herokuapp.com request_id=3dd3d441-e380-410a-bd69-9458b59c1a81 fwd="92.97.70.247" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-11-28T11:59:54.361874+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-11-28T11:59:56.449710+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `: node app.js`
2020-11-28T11:59:58.699972+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-11-28T11:59:58.734578+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

```
---------app.js-----------
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

//set port

let port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

//routes

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.render("index");
})

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log("app running");
})
```

[this is the video I followed to deploy my app](https://medium.com/@blondiebytes/heroku-hosting-put-your-website-on-the-cloud-cdc8729a7e09)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We can't help with more information. For example, your logs say ``Starting process with command `: node app.js` `` and `Process exited with status 0`. Exiting with status 0 usually means the program finished. What is in `app.js`?

Comment: app.js is the main file where I have installed express and body-parser and wrote a few commands to start the server. and i just need to get my app running live and really dont know wats are those logs.

Comment: ...please _show it to us_ by [edit]ing your question. Describing it doesn't tell us much.